# How to send JPEG by HTTP in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, http

I am looking for the simplest way to send JPG image from computer to windwows phone. I have tried to use raw TCP, and there are very subtle problems with that. My friend said that it would be easy to use http instead.

How to send JPEG by HTTP in .NET?

The jpeg is in file `C:\file.jpg` sender ip is `255.224.20.120`, receiver ip is `242.224.10.2`.

Comment: What?  Do you have a service running on the phone to receive the image?

Comment: @zimdanen I do not, I don't have sending and receiving service. That's the question about. Thank you for your help. I partially solved the problem via TCP, but the solution is enermous(I do not want to go offtopic here).

Comment: Do you have a web server involved?

Comment: @mikey There is only PC connected to the internet and telephone connected to the internet.